# My XBOX 360 Kinect app stopped working when I moved it to Windows 8.1

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I finally upgraded my OS to Windows 8.1 and now my XBOX Kinect app that I built doesn't work. Also, none of the example project that come with the SDK and Development tools works either. I have the latest downloads and everything. Windows 8.1 is completely updated too. All the apps run, but it seems none of the sensors work, but the red light comes on when I run the examples. Anyone had this issues before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downgrading back to Windows 7. Not sure what the real solution was, but spent an entire evening trying updates and nothing worked. Just as an FYI I am using an XBOX 360 Kinect and not the Windows version.